# Getting two rows when querying contact from email address

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I'm receiving an email address and I want to get the user's contact_id.

```
String whereClause = null;
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
    //Field requires API level 11
    whereClause = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + " = '" + email + "'";
} else
{
    whereClause = "data1" + " = '" + email + "'";
}

Cursor user = context.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID},
        whereClause,
        null,
        null);

DataUtils.log("In getContactFromEmail, cursor is " + DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(user));
```

The log I'm printing shows the cursor has 2 results:

```
12-07 21:56:51.410: V/talk(7491): In getContactFromEmail, cursor is >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@52a379a4
12-07 21:56:51.410: V/talk(7491): 0 {
12-07 21:56:51.410: V/talk(7491):    contact_id=840
12-07 21:56:51.410: V/talk(7491): }
12-07 21:56:51.410: V/talk(7491): 1 {
12-07 21:56:51.410: V/talk(7491):    contact_id=902
12-07 21:56:51.410: V/talk(7491): }
```

The one I'm expecting is `contact_id=902` and not the first one. I've checked and no other contact in the system has this email.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the email address for contact with id 840?

I'm guessing its maybe because there are different sources the contact may comes from. like Skype, google, devices, etc.

Comment: That's a good question. I'll query for both and see what comes up. I don't think it's from anything other than the "normal" contacts, since I'm using an emulator and don't have anything else installed.

Comment: Just checked, and both contacts have the same email address. In order to send myself a test message I created a contact with my own email address. What I suspect is happening is that there is a "hidden" contact for the phone owner with my email address, and the other is the one I created for testing purposes. That's my guess.